# Nested Loop- VBA- Copy each worksheet where the worksheet name matches file name in specific folder

Tags: excel, vba, nested-loops

**Update 9/21/22- Updated VBA code located below.  I have the sheets being copied from one workbook to the target workbooks; however its not copying only the worksheet with a name that is contained in the target workbook's file name.  Its copying all tabs to each file in target location.  I think I have the order of tasks messed up. It seems like the copying all happens when I debug on "Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFile.Path)". Thank you in Advance!

I am looking to create a nested loop or at least I think that will accomplish this task.   I have a worksheet with individual sheets that I want to copy to existing workbooks.  The target workbooks' file names contain the tab's name within the file name.   I want to loop through each worksheet and add it to the beginning of the matching workbook.

I believe my current struggle is setting the target workbook so i can make changes to it within the 2nd loop.  Thank you in Advance!

```
'''
Sub updates()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\report")


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

If ws.Index > 2 Then
    'folder location
    For Each wbFile In fldr.Files
    
    On Error Resume Next
    If fso.GetExtensionName(InStr(wbFile.Name, ws)) > 0 Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFile.Path)
    ws.Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)

    


    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End If
Next wbFile
    
End If
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
'''
```

Comment: `Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(MySource.Files)` should be `.file`, to match the variable you're referring in `For Each file In MySource.Files`.  You may want to `exit for` in the as well, to move onto the next `ws`.

Comment: You definitely want to comment out the `on error resume next`, which would most likely have flagged that line... and you should most likely create a trap, rather than ignoring an error, e.g., `if no match then msgbox "no match")`

Answer (score 0):

Posting my comments as an answer, which should resolve your issue:

```
Sub updatewkbks()
    toggleAppProperties False
    Dim sourceWS As Worksheet
    For Each sourceWS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'UPDATE - Make sure the first 2 sheets are skipped so we dont creates sheets for them.
        If sourceWS.Index > 2 Then
            Dim MyObj As Object
            Dim folderLocation as Object:  Set folderLocation = MyObj.GetFolder("insertfilelocationhere")
            Dim fileInFolder As Variant
            For Each fileInFolder In folderLocation.Files
                If InStr(fileInFolder.Name, sourceWS) > 0 Then
                    Dim destinationWB As Workbook:  Set destinationWB = Workbooks.Open(MySource.fileInFolder)
                    sourceWS.Copy Before:=destinationWB.Sheets(1)
                    destinationWB.Save
                    destinationWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next fileInFolder
        End If
    Next sourceWS
    toggleAppProperties True
End Sub

Private Sub toggleAppProperties(val as Boolean)
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = val
        .ScreenUpdating = val
    End With
End Sub
```

Added a subroutine to support turning items off, which has a name indicative of its intent.  I also moved your dimensioning of variables to where they are used, whereas you don't need to scroll to a block of dimensions at the top to remember/see what you did.  Some variables have been updated to be more descriptive, where I've removed comments.

Removed `ActiveWorkbook` references in the `.Save/.Close`... verify you're closing the correct one... i referenced `destinationWB`.

---

Edit1:  Removed "=" from the `toggleAppProperties` related to parameters

Comment: I am getting a compile error: Argument not optional on toggleAppProperties = False.

Comment: @dcola12 my bad, the "=" shouldn't be there... it's just `toggleAppProperties False`.  Will update.

Comment: Thank you so much! So I get to set folder location "Set folderLocation = MyObj.GetFolder("C:\Users\colardeaud\Documents\test")  and I get run-time error 91:  Object variable or With Block variable not set.

Comment: @dcola12 i'd look into what `MyObj` is, as it's not defined in your code.  You just list `as Object` and start using it.

Comment: I got it from somewhere else.  I thought it was something I needed to use in order to introduce the file location

Comment: Actually I am super close now!  The only component that is not working is the match.  It seems that each ws from original workbook is being copied to all workbooks in target location.  I only want the ws where the name is represented in the target file to be copied.   I updated the codeblock above.

Comment: @dcola12 Take a look at using `Dir()`, where you can take advantage of a partial name... it may even remove the need for a loop.